# Confusion with "Finite submodules"

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

When we say "finite submodule", what do we generally mean - the order of the submodule is finite or the submodule is finitely generated ?

Comment: I've seen in some books finite instead of finitely generated. I dont think its the best terminology tho.

Comment: Finite could mean finitely generated or actually finite. I also hate this verbiage but it persists. If you want to know the difference in your context, please give the context ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finite module/submodule essentially always means **finitely generated**. If the order of the submodule is intended to be finite, this will almost always (and *should* always) be explicitly specified, e.g. "finite as a set", "finite order", etc. One reason for this is that even cyclic (1-generated) submodules $Rx \subseteq M$ are infinite unless $R/\text{ann}(x)$ is a finite ring. In particular, a module that is torsionfree just as an abelian group (i.e., $\mathbb{Z}$-module) has no submodules of finite order (except the zero submodule).